# How to do a count on a union query

Tags: mysql, sql, union, aggregate-functions

I have the following query:

```
select distinct profile_id from userprofile_...

union

select distinct profile_id from productions_...
```

How would I get the count of the total number of results?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If you want a total count for all records, then you would do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    select distinct profile_id 
    from userprofile_...

    union all

    select distinct profile_id 
    from productions_...
) x
```

Comment: Considering it's from different tables (same name column, but from differents tables), he could lost results if got a same Id in both tables

Comment: should there be one more distinct to remove duplicates between first and second part of union? there might be duplicate profile_id's in userprofile and productions..

Comment: now that you have edited you got the same answer that I posted -.-

Comment: Considering that I posted it first, and I didn't edit my answer, this is at least, really unfair !!! :(

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Timestamps reveal otherwise :(

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy you should consider the edited date because this wasn't the original answer. Either way it's ok, this was long ago :D

Answer (score 24):

you should use `Union All` if there are equals rows in both tables, because Union makes a distinct

```
select count(*) from 
(select distinct profile_id from userprofile_...

union ALL

select distinct profile_id from productions_...) x
```

In this case, if you got a same `Profile_Id` in both tables (id is probably a number, so it's possible), then if you use `Union`, if you got `Id = 1` in both `tables`, you will lose one row (it will appear one time instead of two)

Answer (score 10):

This will perform pretty well:

```
select count(*) from (
    select profile_id
    from userprofile_...
    union
    select profile_id
    from productions_...
) x
```

The use of `union` guarantees distinct values - `union` removes duplicates, `union all` preserves them. This means you don't need the `distinct` keyword (the other answers don't exploit this fact and end up doing more work).

#### Edited:

If you want to total number of different profile_id in each, where given values that appear in both table are considered *different* values, use this:

```
select sum(count) from (
    select count(distinct profile_id) as count
    from userprofile_...
    union all
    select count(distinct profile_id)
    from productions_...
) x
```

This query will out-perform all other answers, because the database can efficiently count distinct values within a table much faster than from the unioned list. The `sum()` simply adds the two counts together.

Comment: Well, you're considering that profile_id will be unique.. If I got 3 id = 1 in productions (could be a FK), and one Id = 1 in userProfile (could be a PK), then the union will give 1 row, instead of 4 (with both distinct will get 2). Then the count will fail. In the query he  posted, he will get a id=1 in each select, the count should be 2

Comment: @ElVieejo That's what I thought he wanted. Edited answer

Answer (score 6):

These will not work if in one of the COUNT(*) the result is equals to 0.

This will be better:

```
SELECT SUM(total)
FROM
(
    select COUNT(distinct profile_id) AS total
    from userprofile_...

    union all

    select COUNT(distinct profile_id) AS total
    from productions_...
) x
```

Answer (score 5):

As omg ponies has already pointed out that there is no use of using distinct with UNION, you can use UNION ALL in your case.....

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
( 
select distinct profile_id from userprofile_...
union all
select distinct profile_id from productions_...
) AS t1
```

Comment: DISTINCT is useless on a `UNION` - it'd only be necessary for `UNION ALL`.  Might not want to copy others answers ;)

Comment: @OMGPonies : BTW, i have not the copy the answer....I got late with fraction of second to post the answer.....

Answer (score 5):

Best solution is to add count of two query results. It will not be a problem if the table contains large number of records. And you don't need to use union query.
Ex:

```
SELECT (select COUNT(distinct profile_id) from userprofile_...) + 
(select COUNT(distinct profile_id) from productions_...) AS total
```