# MySQL Union statement and Count

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences for the same title.

My Code

```
SELECT 

client AS Client,
datescanned as "Date Scanned",
scanner AS Scanner,
risk AS Risk, 
host AS Host, 
name AS Title, 
solution AS Solution
FROM sss1webapp_latest

WHERE risk regexp "Critical|High" 
AND client = "myself" 
group by Title;

UNION

SELECT 


client AS Client,
datescanned as "Date Scanned",
scanner AS Scanner,
AttackScore AS Risk, 
WebSite AS Host, 
AttackType AS Title, 
Recommendation AS Solution
FROM sss2webapp_latest
WHERE AttackScore regexp "5-Critical|4-High" 
AND client = "myself"
```

My Table (just a representation, didn't added all fields...)

```
client  datescanned  title  ....
myself  2019-03-11  Backported Security Patch 
myself  2019-03-11  Backported Security Patch
myself  2019-03-11  Backported Security Patch Detection (SSH)
myself  2019-03-11  Backported Security Patch Detection (SSH)
myself  2019-03-11  Backported Security Patch Detection (SSH)
myself  2019-03-11  Backported Security Patch Detection (SSH)
myself  2019-03-11  SSL Version Issues
```

My desired output

```
count client datescanned title
2     myself  2019-03-11    Backported Security Patch 
4     myself  2019-03-11    Backported Security Patch Detection (SSH)
1     myself  2019-03-11    SSL Version Issues
```

(adding count and group same title and counting the # of occurrences.

Tried adding count(0)as tcount, after the select statement but error.

Feedback welcome!
Thx! Nathalie

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon on your first select statement(`group by Title;#<- get rid of this`), I think you'll need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731655/how-to-do-a-count-on-a-union-query

Answer (score 0):

```
 select count(*) as count, client, datescanned, title, risk AS Risk  
 from sss1webapp_latest 
 where risk regexp "Critical|High" AND client = "myself"  group by title 

 union

 select count(*) as count, client, datescanned, title, AttackScore AS Risk 
 from sss2webapp_latest 
 where AttackScore regexp "5-Critical|4-High" AND client = "myself" group by title
```

you may select other columns but column numbers should be same and the name also for `union`

Comment: Tried that.. if I add count(*) as count in one statement without UNION, it's fine.  However, as soon I add several count(*), i'm getting "cannot calculate position of (0) within UNION SELECT count(0) AS count; client AS Client, datescanned as "Date Scanned........"

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to achieve the desired result using a combination of `count(*)` and `sum(*)`. You probably should be using as a `UNION ALL` instead of a `UNION` as well, as we want duplicate records to be counted. Check out this db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uVbD2izXHGPjCkkyk1GHRn/2

You might have to tweak the query a bit by adding in the extra columns and the where clause.

I pulled together this idea from another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377265/9842191